# VBA: automate selected series last data point labelling in combo chart with series and stacked area

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to add last point data labels to some selected series. I have a combo figure with "line" and "stacked area". I would like to only show last point data label for the "line" series, but not "stacked area", how can I do this in VBA?

I have been able to build a button-click macro to generate data label, but it will generate data label for all series (I don't want it for "stacked area"). See my code below. Can someone enlighten me how to do it please? The reason I'm looping through charts is because I have two charts. The time series are plotted using name ranges for potential update.

Any helpful comments greatly appreciated! If you need further clarification I can provide my excel file (It doesn't seem to give me option to attach it here).

Thanks.

> ```
>  Sub LastDataLables()
>
>      Dim oChart As ChartObject
>      Dim MySeries As Series
>
>      For Each oChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
>        For Each MySeries In oChart.Chart.SeriesCollection
>
>            'Clear ExistingData Labels
>             MySeries.ApplyDataLabels (xlDataLabelsShowNone)
>
>             MySeries.Points(MySeries.Points.Count - 1).ApplyDataLabels
>
>          With MySeries.DataLabels
>            .Font.Size = 12
>           '.Position = xlLabelPositionRight   
>            .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
>          End With
>
>        Next MySeries
>       Next oChart
>  End Sub
> ```

Comment: see my answer and code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this add an `If` criteria to check `If MySeries.Type = xlLine Then`.

***Full Code***:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LastDataLables()

Dim oChart As ChartObject
Dim MySeries As Series

For Each oChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    For Each MySeries In oChart.Chart.SeriesCollection

        If MySeries.Type = xlLine Then ' <-- check if series type is xlline
            'Clear ExistingData Labels
            MySeries.ApplyDataLabels (xlDataLabelsShowNone)
            MySeries.Points(MySeries.Points.Count - 1).ApplyDataLabels

            With MySeries.DataLabels
                .Font.Size = 12
                '.Position = xlLabelPositionRight
                .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
            End With
        End If
    Next MySeries
Next oChart

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! That helps!